# nodejs node-html-parser can't read element's value

Tags: html, node.js, node-html-parser

I am using `node-html-parser` module as below. The html is a simple

```
<div><input type="hidden" value="199,9" ></div>
```

The code is below:

```
   var { parse }   = require('node-html-parser');
   const body = '<div><input type="hidden" value="199,9" ></div>'
   var dom  = parse(body)
   console.dir(dom.querySelectorAll('div input')[0]);
   console.log(`log from  ` + dom.querySelectorAll('div input')[0] );
   console.log(`log from value ` + dom.querySelectorAll('div input')[0].value );
```

output is as

```
log from <input type="hidden" value="199,9" >
log from value undefined
```

the `.value` attribute returns undefined. How can I solve this problem? I just want to use `node-html-parser` module

**EDIT:**

If I run

```
console.dir(dom.querySelectorAll('div input')[0]);
```

I get something such as

```
rawAttrs: 'type="hidden" value="199,9" ',
```

I don't think it is possible to select the attribute alone with this module, so I will need to possibly regex.

Comment: There is no `div` in the HTML you're showing, so the query selector `div input` is nothing. Please remember that if you're showing input, code, and output, you need to make sure that [you verified that the input you show results in the output you show, when run using the code that you show](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ok i am editing. i just tried to put minimal code, as i mentioned i just get undefined on ```.value```

Comment: Please, again, _run the code you're showing_ because what you're showing won't even get to run right now: it'll throw a ReferenceError. Just hardcode ``const body = `<div><input type="hidden" value="199,9" ></div>``, show that getting parsed, and then console log the result of your query selector.

Comment: is it possible to make it a snippet so that it can also run on this page ? is it possible since it requires a module from nodejs ? @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: No, snippets are for browser-code only, so just create a tiny file with only enough code to show off the problem, with that input hardcoded in it, and that you can run on your own computer with `node thatfilename.js`. Confirm it still has the problem you're asking about, and if it does, put that file's content in your post as your [mcve].

Comment: can help me regex what is inside an attribute ?

Comment: Just use the functions that node-html-parser gives you? [It does not support .value](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser#htmlelement-properties), but it _does_ [support .getAttribute()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser#getattributekey-string).

Comment: that easy. thank you